# List all environment parameters using pm2 command

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, pm2

I am recently using pm2 to deploy my server on AWS EC2. I started my production using:

```
pm2 start server
```

where server.js is the main production.

I used some environment variables for the production, and they can be accessed via processes.env.Var_Name.
However, I am not sure if these variables are loaded correctly, so I would like to know how to list all the variables.

I've tried `pm2 show id` or `pm2 describe id` but they does not list the variables properly, the variables are not listed in the output.

Thank you and kind regards.

Answer (score 3):

Try running `pm2 env id`. You can get `id` by running the `pm2 list` command.

*I use it on pm2 version `4.5.6`*